# iOS Add Label on TableCell at Indexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, cell

I'm trying to present a label every time the user double taps on my cell. I can detect the taps and I can execute code from them but I'm having an issue with the labels. For some reason the labels are being added two sometimes three cells below the one it should be added on. I need the label to be added on the cell that was tapped, shouldn't be to hard to do.

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (nil == cell)
    {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFObject *tempObject = [_myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *currentUser = [[PFUser currentUser]username];

    //NSLog(@"%@",tempObject);
    NSArray *test = [tempObject valueForKey:@"Like"];
    //NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)test.count);


    NSTimeInterval now = [[[NSDate alloc] init] timeIntervalSince1970];
    if ((now - lastClick < 0.3) & [indexPath isEqual:lastIndexPath]) {

        //cell.test.hidden = NO;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 80, 40);

        UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        label1.frame = frame;

        label1.text = @"first label";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];


        if ([test containsObject:currentUser]) {
            NSLog(@"1");

            [tempObject removeObject:currentUser forKey:@"Like"];
            [tempObject saveInBackground];

        }else {
            NSLog(@"2");
            [tempObject addUniqueObject:currentUser forKey:@"Like"];
            [tempObject saveInBackground];
        }

    }

    lastClick = now;
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not deque a cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Instead use `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to retrieve the cell at selected index path, like below.

```
Cell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You can call below method at the end of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, if needed.

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: [NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath]
     withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Comment: @iKrish Can I detect if the cell is tapped in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: just replace the 1st portion of the code with 2nd portion of the code, issue will be fixed.

Comment: @iKrish I just did, it's all good now. Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: It won't let me it's too soon :) For some reason when I tap it also adds the label on another cell.

Comment: @iKrish It is still adding the label at the index but its also adding some below it without tapping on those.

Comment: It is not a good idea to create a new views and add them to cell in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Instead, include the label in `Cell ` xib/Class, hide it in `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and enable it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. If you create new views in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath `, it might return the new cell in `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ` which will be a problem for you.

Comment: @iKrish I was doing that but I get `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label` I can't put any labels on my cell.

Comment: No, You can put UILabel on UITableViewCell.